# "couldn't recognize data in image file ..." Why do I (sometimes) get this Error-message?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, tkinter, tcl

I wanted to implement some images in my Python-Tkinter application. I used the `PhotoImage` instance of Tkinter for this. It all worked perfectly whith the first picture: `"RR.gif`, a GIF image made with MS Paint. The second image: `"Tank.gif"`, unfortunately caused some troubles. This picture was made (also in MS Paint) immediately after the first one and was also stored in GIF format. The images are located in the same folder so I assume the path is correct for both of them. However, the second label, (which contains the second image) gives the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "Tank.gif"
```

Which I think is strange since both images files are very similar. Does anyone know why I am getting this error? and how to solve it?

This is the simplest code in which the problem occurs.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

icon = PhotoImage(file="RR.gif") 
tank = PhotoImage(file="Tank.gif")
label_ico = Label(root, image=icon)
label_tan = Label(root, image=tank)
label_ico.pack()
label_tan.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Immediate answer: none of the photo image format handlers liked the data in that file. _Why_ that is the case is what it is hard to guess; is that image file somewhere where we can download it and try it out?

Comment: Though I _bet_ that the problem is the header used is something we don't support. Tk (and so Tkinter) supports GIFs with the `GIF87a` and `GIF89a` magic numbers. Is there another one, another sub-variant of the GIF format?

Comment: @DonalFellows, Thanks, after I checked the image headers I found out 'RR.gif' was a GIF89a but 'Tank.gif' was actually a PNG instead of a GIF ... I resaved the image as a GIF and now it works the way I want. Still don't understand though. It clearly shows the '.gif' extension while the Hex editor is talking about PNG. Strange.

Comment: Some software just doesn't get that stuff right. More usefully, Tk 8.6 handles PNG, but earlier versions require a plugin extension module (`tkimg::png`).